# What is the name of this connector (Apple Time Capsule)?

Tags: power-supply, connector

I salvaged a power supply from an Apple Time Capsule (Delta Electronics ADP-30HF A). This connector was connected to the main board of the time capsule tot supply it with 5.1V.

**What is it called?**

[image: Delta Electronics ADP-30HF A 5.1 volt connector]

Comment: It seems to be a SATA power connector

Comment: @codo I actually mean the one being measured by the caliper, the other one is indeed a SATA power cable

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [Molex 90331](http://www.molex.com/molex/products/listview.jsp?query=90331&path=cHome%23%23-1%23%23-1~~ncCRIMPHOUSINGS%23%230%23%23o&offset=0&autoNav=1&sType=s&filter=boo&fs=&channel=Products) series.

They're currently listed as obsolete and I'm not sure what, if any, parts replace them.

Comment: No.  According to your link the series you nominate has a pitch of 3.96mm, this appears to be 2.54mm aka 0.100" as the caliper is showing 6 pins fit in a 680 mill housing.